# Data Structure for easy look up

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, lookup, java-6

I am looking for a data structure / algorithm in java that does the following -

1. Store the data set into some data structure for easy look up
2. Choose closest (A value to get B) if an exact match doesn't exist
3. If exactly in between, choose higher value of A to get B

I have pairs of numbers, for example -

```
A   B
80  0
76  1
64  3
56  4
48  10
```

I would only know value of A and should find out / derive the value of B by doing a straight lookup by applying above rules.

Examples - 1

If I get value as 80, output is 0

Example - 2

If I get value as 75, output is 1 [as per rule 2]

Example - 3

If I get value as 70, output is 1 [as per rule 3]

Any advice?

Updates based on Comments - 
log(N) lookup is acceptable. I am open to implementing it myself but needs suggestions on how to achieve it. Range of A varies between 0 to 1000 with 1 digit precision points.

Comment: Create your own `Map` implementation. It is very specific issue, I'm sure there isn't  any ready solution for it.

Comment: Are you looking for something that is already created or are you open to answers where you would be implementing it yourself?

Comment: Noticed there is a question on Stack that matches closely... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482988/find-the-closest-answer-in-hashmap

Comment: What is the range where A can vary? It's one thing if A belongs to [0, 255] let's say, it's another thing if A can be any int. How simple do you need this lookup to be: is a log(N) lookup OK (where N is the count of As)?

Comment: This looks like homework and the goal seems to be to write a custom binary search algorithm as per one of the answers. Should be pretty straightforward! Good luck!

Comment: Surely, if the range is fixed, a pre-processed array from `0..1000` would give you `O(1)` lookups...

Comment: @Giovanni Botta - I already mentioned this is not a homework problem. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's actually already a data structure which does exactly what you're looking for, which is the [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

It has methods which allow you to get the 'floor' and 'ceiling' of a key.  After that a little math will get you the value you actually want to return:

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    tm.put(80, 0);
    tm.put(76, 1);
    tm.put(64, 3);
    tm.put(56, 4);
    tm.put(48, 10);

    System.out.println(myGet(80));  // 0
    System.out.println(myGet(75));  // 1
    System.out.println(myGet(70));  // 1
}

public static int myGet(int key) {
    Integer value = tm.get(key);

    if (value == null) {
        Entry<Integer, Integer> floor = tm.floorEntry(key);
        Entry<Integer, Integer> ceiling = tm.ceilingEntry(key);

        if ((key - floor.getKey()) < (ceiling.getKey() - key)) {
            value = floor.getValue();
        } else {
            value = ceiling.getValue();
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Note: I didn't bother with proper `null` checking for when there is no floor/ceiling, but you get the idea.

Comment: What if I have same key with different values?

Comment: i guess I changed the TreeMap definition to TreeMap<Double, List<Double>> and it should probably work

Answer (score 1):

Store A and B in arrays/lists ordered by values in A.

Use modified form of binary search to lookup exact or closest value of A (to satisfy conditions 2 & 3).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a homework assignment, so my answer will be in the form of an algorithm suggestion.

Store the pairs of values in a two dimensional array, stored in ascending order of "A".  TO find the result, use a binary search to find the "closest low value of A), if that is not exact, use the index+1.

Comment: Sorry, if it sounded so, but it is not a homework assignment. It is a real-time problem.