# How to get map values from a float

Tags: java, math

I have a map that I want to use like a mathematical function on the real line, i.e. I give it a floating point value, it returns a floating point value.

If had something like this:

```
Map<Double, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I could get null when trying to access a value because of floating point imprecision. For this reason, it's not wise to use floating point values as the key to a map.

What's the best way to achieve my goal? I need to have a map of (x, y) values that allows me to get a y value from an x value. I suppose there's some other data type or something that doesn't allow imprecision?

All answers are appreciated thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you apparently think 'get(0.5)' will return the only entry, whose key is 1.0.  Floating point may be imprecise, but not **that** imprecise!

Comment: But maybe a NavigableMap would do the job for you. You can use floorEntry and/or ceilingEntry, and then decide if the key is 'close enough'.

Comment: Whoops typo, but I have gotten null in my program with the right value, and I've read that it's not a good idea for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: You could try rounding the key to *n* decimals before lookup. Or search the map. Or use BigDecimal. It really depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482988/find-the-closest-answer-in-hashmap

Comment: A Java Map is probably not a good type to represent a mathematical function because of those reasons.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for that suggestion, I might look into BigDecimal, but I'll probably use the closest n decimals. NavigableMap also looks promising.

Comment: Why does it have to be a map? Is an actual method not an option? (And why not?)

Comment: If  you want the map to represent a step function defined everywhere on the x axis, then the `NavigableMap` (like `TreeMap`) idea of @ArfurNarf is definitely a way to go.  If you won't add or delete items after initial creation, a simple sorted array and binary search (for least not less than or greatest not greater than) will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: if your data is continuous you might use bilinear or bicubic interpolation instead of hash map

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I could get null when trying to access a value because of floating point imprecision. For this reason, it's not wise to use floating point values as the key to a map. ..."*

Use the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class.

```java
class DoubleMap extends HashMap<BigDecimal, Double> {
    Double put(String k, Double v) {
        return super.put(new BigDecimal(k), v);
    }

    Double get(String k) {
        for (Entry<BigDecimal, Double> e : entrySet())
            if (e.getKey().toPlainString().equals(k))
                return e.getValue();
        return null;
    }
}
DoubleMap map = new DoubleMap();
map.put("1.23", 4.56);
```